# Difference between "as.numeric" and "as.POSIXct.numeric" (only the first seems to work)?

Tags: r, date, posixct

I am struggling with `as.POSIXct.numeric`. The following code works:

```
dates <- structure(c(1649285787, 1651134684), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                   tzone = "UTC")
lims <- as.numeric(dates)
limits <- as.POSIXct.numeric(lims, origin = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"))
plot(stepfun(x = dates, # OK
             y = c(0, 1, 2)),
     do.points = FALSE)
plot(stepfun(x = dates, # OK 
             y = c(0, 1, 2)),
     do.points = FALSE, 
     xlim = lims)
```

However, the following fails and I don't understand why (I need to specify the limits):

```
plot(stepfun(x = dates, # Not OK
             y = c(0, 1, 2)),
     do.points = FALSE, 
     xlim = dates)
# Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
plot(stepfun(x = dates, # Not OK
             y = c(0, 1, 2)),
     do.points = FALSE, 
     xlim = limits)
# Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Does anybody understand this behavior? I explicitly specified the origin in `as.POSIXct.numeric(lims, origin = ...)`!

Comment: The difference is that `as.numeric` converts to numeric, whereas `as.POSIXct.numeric` is a `POSIXct` class. `class(limits)#
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" #
> class(lims)#
[1] "numeric"`

Comment: @akrun but why does it complain, although I explicitly define `limits <- as.POSIXct.numeric(lims, origin = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"))`?

Comment: There is only a tz difference between your dates and limits `all.equal(dates, limits)#
[1] "'tzone' attributes are inconsistent ('UTC' and '')"`

Comment: The think is that not ALL the functions has a Date method, i.e. not ALL functions "know" how to deal (work) with Date objects. I am not familiarized with `stepfun` function, but it is a clearly example of a functions that only work with numeric vectors.

Comment: @akrun Do you know a solution? I even define `tz = "UTC"` in `origin`...

Comment: If you check the `traceback()` the `xlim=dates` is from `...`, there is a step which does `lapply(list(...), function(e) unclass(as.POSIXct(e)))` and results in error.  It is from `plot.stepfun`

Comment: According to `?plot.window` `xlim, ylim - numeric vectors of length 2, giving the x and y coordinates ranges.`. It is having an additional attribute, and thus may be messing in the plot.stepfun

Comment: `ti <- c(xlim[1L] - dr, xval, xlim[2L] + dr)#
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied` gets the error, which may work if we change the 'xval' which is numeric where as others are POSIXct i.e. `ti <- c(xlim[1L] - dr, as.POSIXct(xval, origin = '1970-01-01'),  xlim[2L] + dr)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the first chunk works is because `stepfun(x = dates, y = c(0, 1, 2))` returns an object of class "stepfun" (you can check it by running `class(stepfun(x = dates, y = c(0, 1, 2)))`) and the plot method for stepfun objects will make a plot setting the X and Y axis as numerical. In other words, your first chunk works because the `xlim` was set as numerical (which is what plot method for stepfun objects expects). Conversely, when you set the `xlim` with a `POSIX` vector (`dates` or `limits`), the plot method simply does not what to do with them because it is expecting a numeric vector.

If you need to change the axis labels, I suggest doing it externaly as follows:

```
plot(stepfun(x = dates, 
             y = c(0, 1, 2)),
     do.points = FALSE, 
     xlim = lims, axes = FALSE)

xLabels <- pretty(limits)
axis(side = 1, at = as.numeric(xLabels), labels = xLabels)
axis(side = 2)
box()
```

`pretty` function is just a quickly way to find out vector of "pretty" (rounded) break points, but can use another way to set that values.

Comment: Simple solution :-)

Answer (score 4):

We might try to hack the `plot.stepfun` function by doing some date conversion stuff from line 30 on. More specifically we convert the `xlim=` in `"POSIXt"` format to a `seq`uence of dates and use it in line 63 as values for the `axis`.

```
plot_stepfun <- function(x, xval, xlim, ylim=range(c(y, Fn.kn)), xlab="x", 
                         ylab="f(x)", main=NULL, add=FALSE, verticals=TRUE, 
                         do.points=(n < 1000), pch=par("pch"), col=par("col"), 
                         col.points=col, cex.points=par("cex"), col.hor=col, 
                         col.vert=col, lty=par("lty"), lwd=par("lwd"), ...) {
  if (!is.stepfun(x)) {
    if (is.numeric(x)) {
      sarg <- substitute(x)
      x <- ecdf(x)
      attr(x, "call") <- call("ecdf", sarg)
    }
    else stop("'plot.stepfun' called with wrong type of argument 'x'")
  }
  if (missing(main)) {
    cl <- attr(x, "call")
    main <- if (is.null(cl)) sys.call() else cl
  }
  knF <- knots(x)
  xval <- if (missing(xval)) 
    knF
  else sort(xval)
  if (missing(xlim)) {
    rx <- range(xval)
    dr <- if (length(xval) > 1L) 
      max(0.08 * diff(rx), median(diff(xval)))
    else abs(xval)/16
    xlim <- rx + dr * c(-1, 1)
  }
  else {
    xlim1 <- xlim
    xlim <- as.numeric(xlim)
    if (inherits(xlim1, c('Date', "POSIXt"))) {
      tz <- attributes(as.POSIXlt(xlim1))$tzone
      xlim2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(strftime(xlim1, '%F')), tz=tz[length(tz)])
      if (as.numeric(difftime(xlim2[2], xlim2[1], units='secs')) < 86400) {
        stop('will be implemented soon :)')
      } else {
        xseq <- seq.POSIXt(xlim2[1], xlim2[2], by='days')
        if (length(xseq) > 6) {
          xseq <- xseq[(seq_along(xseq) - 5) %% ceiling(length(xseq)/6) == 0]
        }
      }
    }
    dr <- diff(xlim)
  }
  xval <- xval[xlim[1L] - dr <= xval & xval <= xlim[2L] + dr]
  ti <- c(xlim[1L] - dr, xval, xlim[2L] + dr)
  ti.l <- ti[-length(ti)]
  ti.r <- ti[-1L]
  y <- x(0.5 * (ti.l + ti.r))
  n <- length(y)
  Fn.kn <- x(xval)
  dev.hold()
  on.exit(dev.flush())
  if (add) 
    segments(ti.l, y, ti.r, y, col=col.hor, lty=lty, 
             lwd=lwd, ...)
  else {
    if (missing(ylim)) 
      ylim <- range(c(y, Fn.kn))
    plot(NA, NA, type="n", xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xlab=xlab, 
         ylab=ylab, main=main, xaxt='n', ...)
    if (exists('xseq')) {
      axis(1, xseq, xseq)
    } else {
      axis(1, at=axTicks(1), labels=axTicks(1))
    }
    segments(ti.l, y, ti.r, y, col=col.hor, lty=lty, 
             lwd=lwd)
  }
  if (do.points) 
    points(xval, Fn.kn, pch=pch, col=col.points, cex=cex.points)
  if (verticals) 
    segments(xval, y[-n], xval, y[-1L], col=col.vert, lty=lty, 
             lwd=lwd)
  invisible(list(t=ti, y=y))
}
```

```
plot_stepfun(stepfun(x=dates, y=c(0, 1, 2)), do.points=FALSE)  ## works!
plot_stepfun(stepfun(x=dates, y=c(0, 1, 2)), do.points=FALSE, xlim=lims)  ## works!
plot_stepfun(stepfun(x=dates, y=c(0, 1, 2)), do.points=FALSE, xlim=dates)  ## works!
plot_stepfun(stepfun(x=dates, y=c(0, 1, 2)), do.points=FALSE, xlim=limits)  ## works!
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dates <- structure(c(1649285787, 1651134684), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")
lims <- as.numeric(dates)
limits <- as.POSIXct.numeric(lims, origin=as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz="UTC"))
```

Comment: The other answer is just shorter, that's why I accepted it. But you'll get a bounty for your explanations - I learnt a lot ;-)